# Gnome 3 notification not working after switching back from XFCE 4

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, xfce, notifications

I'm using Archlinux. I've recently switched back from XFCE 4 to Gnome 3. So i reinstalled `notification-daemon` (since there was a conflict between it and XFCE 4 notification daemon)

```
pacman -S notification-daemon
```

.. and removed `xfce4-notifyd`

```
pacman -R xfce4-notifyd
```

But now, notification in Gnome 3 is not working at all. I don't know what else should i do.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try `notify-osd` https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=25256

Comment: @jasonwryan Thanks, but i want the native notification daemon in Gnome 3 .. i really like it.

Comment: Do you get any error using it from the command line? `notify-send "Test message..."`

Comment: Nope.. I don't get anything.. and no notification appears as well.

Comment: Well, the last thing I can suggest is a reinstall: `pacman -Syy && pacman -S notification-daemon gtk3 libcanberra`

Comment: @jasonwryan I just noticed when i try `notify-send "test msg"` it shows in the bottom right in the notification area when i hover on it with my mouse. But i need the notification when the whole bottom panel shows the notification.

Comment: See: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=87934

Comment: Opriginal Poster, please, comment whether this helped.

Comment: @Gryllida Sorry, i don't really remember whether if it worked or not, it was a while ago. But i always leave a comment if it helped so i guess it didn't, you can try it yourself though. Good luck.